# Issue to build vue-custom-element embeddable in another website

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I want to use one component of my Vue website on another website by embedding it in HTML.
I decided to use `https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element` and reference to this guide.

I tried the following in my `main.js` file after installing **vue-custom-element** and **document-register-element** npm packages.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import vueCustomElement from 'vue-custom-element';
import 'document-register-element/build/document-register-element';
import reusableComponent from './components/reusableComponent.vue';

Vue.use(vueCustomElement);
Vue.customElement('reusable-component', reusableComponent);
```

And then I was trying to use  on another website like that.

```
<reusable-component><reusable-component />
<link href="/dist/static/css/app.36dd3e0b96e06ae6f3130a58cf185192.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js">. 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/static/js/vendor.614f0593bd5c53cf6320.js">. 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/static/js/app.1c44a427c10b2e559de0.js"></script>
```

But before I tried to use the reusable component in another website, my main website was crashed by this error.

[image: vu]

Has anyone faced this issue before?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not correct use of `vue-custom-element`.
If you are going to use the whole project as a widget for the different project, it would be possible.

```
Vue.customElement('reusable-component', reusableComponent);
```

So, this library is to import the App.vue, not only specific component of the project.

```
Vue.customElement('reusable-component', App);
```